# Upload Image on TryStack Server using Packer tool

Tags: openstack, packer

I am trying to create and upload an ubuntu based image on trystack server using packer tool. I am using Windows OS to do it. I have created a sample template and loads a script file for setting environment variables using chef. But when I am running the packer build command I get

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* Get /: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

**What am I missing in this ??**

Here are the template and script files

template.json

```
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "openstack",
            "ssh_username": "root",
            "image_name": "sensor-cloud",
            "source_image": "66a14661-2dfb-4370-b6d4-87aaefcffdce",
            "flavor": "3",
            "availability_zone": "nova",
            "security_groups": ["mySecurityGroup"]
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "sensorCloudCookbook.zip",
            "destination": "/tmp/sensorCloudCookbook.zip"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"
            ],
            "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; sudo -E {{ .Path }}"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "unzip /tmp/sensorCloudCookbook.zip -d /tmp/sensorCloudCookbook"
            ],
            "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; sudo -E {{ .Path }}"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "chef-solo -c /tmp/sensorCloudCookbook/solo.rb -l info -L /tmp/sensorCloudLogs.txt"
            ],
            "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; sudo -E {{ .Path }}"
        }
    ]
}
```

openstack-config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# To use an OpenStack cloud you need to authenticate against the Identity
# service named keystone, which returns a **Token** and **Service Catalog**.
# The catalog contains the endpoints for all services the user/tenant has
# access to - such as Compute, Image Service, Identity, Object Storage, Block
# Storage, and Networking (code-named nova, glance, keystone, swift,
# cinder, and neutron).
#
# *NOTE*: Using the 2.0 *Identity API* does not necessarily mean any other
# OpenStack API is version 2.0. For example, your cloud provider may implement
# Image API v1.1, Block Storage API v2, and Compute API v2.0. OS_AUTH_URL is
# only for the Identity API served through keystone.
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://128.136.179.2:5000/v2.0

# With the addition of Keystone we have standardized on the term **tenant**
# as the entity that owns the resources.
export OS_TENANT_ID=trystack_tenant_id
export OS_TENANT_NAME="trystack_tenant_name"
export OS_PROJECT_NAME="trystack_project_name"

# In addition to the owning entity (tenant), OpenStack stores the entity
# performing the action as the **user**.
export OS_USERNAME="same_as_trystack_tenant_name"

# With Keystone you pass the keystone password.
echo "Please enter your OpenStack Password: "
read -sr OS_PASSWORD_INPUT
export OS_PASSWORD=$OS_PASSWORD_INPUT

# If your configuration has multiple regions, we set that information here.
# OS_REGION_NAME is optional and only valid in certain environments.
export OS_REGION_NAME="RegionOne"
# Don't leave a blank variable, unset it if it was empty
if [ -z "$OS_REGION_NAME" ]; then unset OS_REGION_NAME; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to source `openstack-config.sh` before packer build.